# Prevent Cursor Change When Resizing & Delphi Styles Used

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

I have a sizeable form that can be resized horizontally but not vertically (I have set constraints.minwidth to the initial width of the form. I want to keep the cursor from changing to the resize cursor when the cursor is over the left of right border or a corner; the cursor should only change when over the top or bottom border. There is a solution to this that works without VCL styles: http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.vcl.using/how-to-hide-resize-mouse-cursor/1071845. However, I have the same requirement except that I am using a VCL Style (Luna) and it appears that WM_NCHITTEST is not fired when a style is used and the example in the link does not work.

How can I prevent the cursor from changing to the resize cursor when a VCL style is used?

Comment: It is fired it just never reaches YOUR handler. You will have to investigate the style engine source and look for where it listens for or hooks WM_NCHITTEST

Answer (score 1):

Style hook messages are branched from `WndProc` of a `TWinControl`. If a style hook reports that a message is handled, `WndProc` returns and the message is not dispatched. That's why a `WM_NCHITTEST` message handler of the form is not fired when it is styled.

So, one option is to override `WndProc` of the form.

```
type
  TTestForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
    ...

procedure TTestForm.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Message.Msg = WM_NCHITTEST) and (Message.Result in [HTLEFT, HTRIGHT]) then
    Message.Result := HTBORDER;
end;
```

Another option is to use a descendant of the style hook in use that overrides the message's  handling.

```
type
  TTestForm = class(TForm)
    ...
  end;

implementation

uses
  themes;   

type
  TTestFormStyleHook = class(TFormStyleHook)
  protected
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  end;

procedure TTestFormStyleHook.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Result of
    HTLEFT, HTRIGHT: Message.Result := HTBORDER;
    HTTOPLEFT, HTTOPRIGHT: Message.Result := HTTOP;
    HTBOTTOMLEFT, HTBOTTOMRIGHT: Message.Result := HTBOTTOM;
  end;
end;

initialization
  TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TTestForm, TTestFormStyleHook);

end.
```